# sed and awk: how to replace a section of file to another content?

Tags: sed, awk

File a.html:

```
<!--TEMPLATE: banner-->
blahblah
<!--TEMPLATE-END: banner-->
```

I want to replace the middle text to some other text, how to achieve that using sed/awk/other tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the new banner text in another file:

```
awk -v new_file=new_banner.txt '
    /!--TEMPLATE:/ {print; system("cat " new_file); banner=1; next}
    /!--TEMPLATE-END:/ {banner=0}
    banner {next}
    {print}
' a.html
```

Answer (score 5):

If the text between the marker lines consists of one or more lines:

```
sed '/<!--TEMPLATE: banner-->/,/<!--TEMPLATE-END: banner-->/ {//!d}; /<!--TEMPLATE: banner-->/aSome text to insert' a.html
```

The `i` command could be changed to an `r` command and a file name to read the text from a file.

```
sed '/<!--TEMPLATE: banner-->/,/<!--TEMPLATE-END: banner-->/ {//!d}; /<!--TEMPLATE: banner-->/r filename' a.html
```

Comment: This did not work on Mac OS X. Presuming this might be a GNU sed feature only.

Comment: *BSD (including OSX) `sed` requires a semicolon before the closing brace. This uses features of `sed` which are poorly standardized, so you may need to experiment with newlines and backslashes -- see your local `sed` documentation for how it likes the `a` command to be formatted, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 'N;s/(<!--TEMPLATE: banner-->\n).*/\1lalala/'
```

#### Input

```
$ cat sedbanner
<!--TEMPLATE: banner-->
blahblah
<!--TEMPLATE-END: banner-->
```

#### Output

```
$ sed -r 'N;s/(<!--TEMPLATE: banner-->\n).*/\1lalala/' ./sedbanner
<!--TEMPLATE: banner-->
lalala
<!--TEMPLATE-END: banner-->
```

If you like the output then replace `sed -r` with `sed -ri` to make it an in-place edit

Comment: this solution can't apply if I have multiple line inside the comments, right?