# How to replace a multi line string in a bunch files

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/bin/sh
old="hello"
new="world"
sed -i s/"${old}"/"${new}"/g $(grep "${old}" -rl *)
```

The preceding script just work for single line text, how can I write a script can replace
a multi line text.

```
old='line1
line2
line3'

new='newtext1
newtext2'
```

What command can I use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed and awk: how to replace a section of file to another content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311915/sed-and-awk-how-to-replace-a-section-of-file-to-another-content)

Answer (score 1):

`awk` can do that for you.

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="" }
  FILENAME==ARGV[1] { s=$0 }
  FILENAME==ARGV[2] { r=$0 }
  FILENAME==ARGV[3] { sub(s,r) ; print }
' FILE_WITH_CONTENTS_OF_OLD FILE_WITH_CONTENTS_OF_NEW ORIGINALFILE > NEWFILE
```

But you can do it with `vim` [like described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/596781/11621) (scriptable solution).

Also see [this](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.21) and [this](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.23.3) in the sed faq.

Answer (score 1):

You could use perl or awk, and change the record separator to something else than newline (so you can match against bigger chunks. For example with awk:

```
echo -e "one\ntwo\nthree" | awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n"} sub(/two\nthree\n, "foo")'
```

or with perl (-00 == paragraph buffered mode)

```
echo -e "one\ntwo\nthree" | perl -00 -pne 's/two\nthree/foo/'
```

I don't know if there's a possibility to have no record separator at all (with perl, you could read the whole file first, but then again that's not nice with regards to memory usage)